# Can I carry hair oil and shampoo in my hand baggage?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security

I am travelling domestically in India via "Air India". I need to carry hair oil and hair shampoo (both 100 ml, total 200 ml). Am I allowed to carry these items in my hand baggage?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can.

If you take liquids in your hand luggage: containers must hold no more than 100ml. Containers must be in a single, transparent, resealable plastic bag, which holds no more than a litre and measures approximately 20cm x 20cm. Contents must fit inside the bag so it can be sealed.

Comment: Just to be precise, the containers capacity must not exceed 100ml. A 200ml which contains only 50ml is not accepted, for instance.